# Kubernetes - Getting IPs of pods of a proxy service

Tags: kubernetes

I have a proxy service that wraps 3 pods (say pod A, pod B, pod C). Some container inside pod A needs to get virtual IPs of other two pods. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Two options:

1. Talk to the Kubernetes API to get the endpoints for the service. (either with `kubectl get endpoints SVCNAME` or by GETing the `/api/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/endpoints/{svcname}` path on the apiserver)
2. Less likely to be of use, but if you [create a service without a cluster IP](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/user-guide/services.md#headless-services), the DNS for that service will return a list of the IP addresses of the backing pods rather than a virtual IP address.

The IPs returned in either case are the IP addresses of all the pods backing the service.

Comment: I would go with 1st option. But the issue is I need to call that API staying within a container of pod A. Is there a way that pod A knows the IP / url of apiserver?

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.1/docs/user-guide/accessing-the-cluster.md#accessing-the-api-from-a-pod